# SQLAlchemy declarative: table without any primary keys?

Tags: database-design, orm, sqlalchemy, schema

How to create a table using ORM Declarative class without primary key?
It failed to start if i didn't make any column the `primary_key = True`.

Comment: may I ask, why would you want to do such a thing?

Comment: @JonathanOng Because I would like to add some indexes later, and it seems that mysql can do something like this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

SQLAlchemy core doesn't complain about missing primary key, so it's possible to create such table with `Table(…)`. But ORM by design requires a way to identify the row corresponding to object, so it's not possible to use table without primary key in ORM.

Why do you need to add this index later? Is it real requirement or an attempt to solve some problem that probably can be solved other way? In case you need composite primary key, it's possible to define it with either `primary_key=True` argument in several `Column`s or by specifying `PrimaryKeyConstraint(…)` in `__table_args__`.

Comment: I intend to create a multi-column index. And it would be great if I could explicitly declare that the index must be constructed using BTREE(my database is MySQL). Any solutions?

Comment: The most databases (including MySQL) use B-Tree by default, so just specify `primary_key=True` in all `Column`s participating in composite index. Explicit B-Tree (or other type) specification is supported in `Index(…)` e.g. for PostgreSQL, but not for MySQL and not in `PrimaryKeyConstraint`. Looks like missing feature in SQLAlchemy.

Comment: you can also put the list of columns that are "primary" in the "primary_key" argument to mapper(), with declarative `__mapper_args__ = {"primary_key":(col1, col2)}}`

Comment: @zzzeek Maybe something wrong with your provided code, which is not adding any primary multi-column key. What's wrong?

Comment: the `__mapper_args__` thing just maps those columns as primary, it wouldn't emit the CREATE TABLE statement.   Otherwise update here with a specific code example and what isn't working correctly.

Comment: @zzzeek `class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'primary_key':[id]
    }`  You mean 'id' is just regarded as primary_key in ORM but created in database?