# Python SQLAlchemy Basic Structure

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have been watching a few videos and reading various posts to try and understand the basic structure of SQLAlchemy in a python script.

**Can anyone tell me:**

1. Why the below script fails

**Script:**

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Records(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'records'

    data1 = Column(Text())
    data2 = Column(Text())
    data3 = Column(Text())
    data4 = Column(Text())



if __name__ == "__main__":
    engine = create_engine('mysql://user:password@localhost/database')
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine, checkfirst=True)
```

**It fails with**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sqltest.py", line 6, in <module>
    class Records(Base):
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/api.py", line 55, in __init__
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 88, in _as_declarative
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 103, in setup_mapping
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 135, in __init__
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 138, in _early_mapping
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 530, in map
  File "<string>", line 2, in mapper
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 629, in __init__
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1223, in _configure_pks
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper Mapper|Records|records could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'records'
```

Am I forced to use a primary key? Or is this to do with the way I call the Records Class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message indicates a primary key is mandatory. No reason to not have one anyways, otherwise you wont be able to express any table relationships.

In response to your comment:
If you rely on using an existing database scheme which lacks primary keys you can try what zzzeek (the author of SQLAlchemy) proposed in his comment to this question: [SQLAlchemy declarative: table without any primary keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8973877/sqlalchemy-declarative-table-without-any-primary-keys), thus use for example

```
__mapper_args__ = {"primary_key":(data1, data2)}}
```

if (data1, data2) identify a table row. And there should be a way to identify table a table row, otherwise you have a severe design problem.

Comment: How can I move ahead without a Primary key for this table?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you nucleon, I moved the Class to this primary_key class and specifying that the data1 column be a String with length 17 in order for it to be a primary key.

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Records(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'records'

    data1 = Column(String(17), primary_key=True)
    data2 = Column(Text())
    data3 = Column(Text())
    data4 = Column(Text())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    engine = create_engine('mysql://user:passwd@localhost/database')
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine, checkfirst=True)
```

Comment: Ok, that's interesting. I didn't know text columns cannot be primary keys. That's probably due to their variable length and that they are stored not in the actual table, but externally. If you have it in your hand I would still vouch for an integer primary key.

Comment: moving to integer is not going to be possible. The data1 field contains mac_addresses in format A1:B2:C3:D4:E5. Thanks for the guidance.